# Unable to set the checkbox class checked inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

With the following HTML, I'm trying to set the checkbox present under the below div to checked.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="prd-items-detials">
        <ul>
            <li class="head">
                <form>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="69" data-mini="true" id_attr="69" />
                    <label item_id_itr_some="69" class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Cold Tea, Fresh Chai gold Ice</label> 
                    <i class="delete-item-btn"></i> 
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt">
                <div class="col"> 
                    <span class="prd-sm-img">                         
                        <img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40" src="http://192.168.2.46:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg" />                         
                        <span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    <i class="minus" id_attr="69"></i>  
                    <i class="qt qt_69" id_attr="69">1</i>  
                    <i class="plus" id_attr="69"></i> 
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    <a style="display:block" id="69" vendor_items_id="83" class="btn btn-sm topp" data-count="2">Topping  <span>2</span>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class="price" style="display:none;">75</div>
                <div class="col total total-rs total_69" id_attr="69">785</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var activehtml = $("#addtoordersdiv" + v_item_id).html();
var buildcart = $('<div id="' + v_item_id + '" class="activateUiHTML"  data-role="collapsible">');
buildcart.append(activehtml);
$('#' + v_item_id + '.activateUiHTML').find(".checkboxclas").prop('checked', true);
```

This doesn't work as expected.
But the same piece of code:

```
var v_item_id = 69;
$('#' + v_item_id + '.activateUiHTML').find(".checkboxclas").prop('checked', true);
```

Works fine when tested in the browsers' console.

Comment: Are you missing the document ready handler?

Comment: I dont know what is document ready handler , could you please elobrate it .

Comment: @user974802 `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: add your js code inside the following script `$(document).ready(function(){ /* here is your code */ });`

Comment: `jQuery` execute in `async` mode, so when the `.find` function is reached, the `$('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML')` object doesn't exist yet. It's not a `Document Ready` problem, it's a `timming and async Mode` stuff

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
var v_item_id = 69 ;
    $('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".checkboxclas").prop('checked',true);
```

because you've specified value of `v_item_id` in it before setting the checked property of checkbox where as in

```
var activehtml = $("#addtoordersdiv"+v_item_id).html();
var buildcart = $('<div id="' + v_item_id + '" class="activateUiHTML"  data-role="collapsible">');
buildcart.append(activehtml);
$('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".checkboxclas").prop('checked',true);
```

it shows an error message `v_item_id is not defined` in console. Hence it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesnt have document.ready.
Add this line to your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var v_item_id = 69 ;
    $('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".checkboxclas").prop('checked',true);  
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/ShVU7GVBDxBvN2tMDXh5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks , I dont want to have this under the document.ready function as this should not be called during page load time .

Comment: so when do you want it then?

Comment: This happens under a listener . whcih i have got for a checkboxevent .